# How to solve recurrence T(n) = T(n-c) +T(c) + n^2

Tags: algorithm, tree, recurrence

I have the recurrence function 
**T(n) = T(n-c) +T(c) + n²**

Can you explain how can I calculate the height of the recurrence tree when:

1. **c** has an indefinite value
2. **c** = n/3  => **T(n) = T(n-(n/3)) +T(n/3) + n²**

I think in the first case T(n) costs θ(n³) and in the second case θ(n²), is it right?

Answer (score 1):

1) if `c` is a constant then you can ignore the `T(c)` term, and it will indeed be `θ(n³)`.

2) when it is `n/3` or some other factor, look for the `T()` term with the largest coefficient on `n` - this leads to the longest branch. Then the upper bound on the time complexity is given by replacing all other `T` terms with this one.

Example: `T(2n/3) + T(n/3) + n² < 2T(2n/3) + n²`, and from the [Master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) this is indeed `θ(n²)`.